# Word length counter isn't counting single quotation as a character

Tags: c, string, counter

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define SIZE 100

const char delim[] = ", . - !*()&^%$#@<> ? []{}";

 int main(void)
{
int length[SIZE] = { 0 };
int name[SIZE];
int i = 0, ch;
int wordlength = 0;
int occurence = 0;

printf("Please enter sentence, end the setence with proper punctuation(! . ?)  : ");

while (1)
{
    ch = getchar();

    if (isalpha(ch))
    {
         ++wordlength;
    }
    else if (strchr(delim, ch))
    {
        if (wordlength)
        {
            length[wordlength - 1]++;
        }

        if(ch == '.' || ch == '?' || ch == '!')
        {
            break;
        }

        if(ch == '\'')
        {
            wordlength++;
        }

        wordlength = 0;
     }
 }

printf("Word Length \tOccurence \n");

for(i = 0; i<sizeof(length) / sizeof(*length); ++i)
{
    if(length[i])
    {
        printf(" %d \t\t%d\n", i + 1, length[i]);
    }
}

 return 0;
}
```

So the program should count take a sentence such as...

```
 "Hello how are you?"
```

Then output:

```
  5 Letter Words -> 1
  3 Letter Words -> 3
```

However I want it to also count a single quotation as a character, for example...

Input:

```
  " 'Tis good. "
```

Output:

```
 4 Letter words -> 2
```

I have tried using...

```
  if(ch == '\'')
        {
            wordlength++;
        }
```

But it just doesnt count the single quotation as a character.

Comment: Why do you need to escape the single quote?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `continue` from your `if (ch =='\'') { ... }`; that is why the `wordlength` is zeroed immediately afterwards.

Another solution would be to include `'` in the first `if` condition:

```
if (isalpha(ch) || ch == '\'') {
    wordlength ++;
}
```